# LA Supershuttle refund

Tags: usa, airport-transfer

I booked supershuttle service to pick me up between 4:25pm and 4:40pm and drive me to the airport. However when I arrived there around 4:35pm the bus just left in front of me. I chased the bus and shouted but in vain. Then I spent 30 min calling them and was told that the time range they provided with me was just for the driver and I should have arrived earlier than 4:25pm. I requested a refund over the phone and they said they could file a report and couldn't guarantee when I would get the result or whether it would succeed.

Does anyway know how to get the refund or increase the probability of getting it?

Thanks

Comment: I think they are right about the time window.  When I've used the service, it's been very clear that the van will arrive sometime during the time window and the passenger has to be ready whenever it comes, meaning you have to be there at the start time.  I don't think you have much chance, sorry.

Comment: I would not see the point of giving *you* the choice in the range. If they meant that you can get there anytime between 4:25 and 4:40, they would have just said "be there at 4:40".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Whenever you are given a time range like this for something like a shuttle, it means that they expect to arrive to pick you up somewhere within that range - and thus you should be ready before the initial time stated.

As well as being common sense, this is also clearly stated on the [Supershuttle Website](http://www.supershuttle.com/terms)

> The vehicle should arrive within the 15-minute window selected at the
>   time of booking. **It is the customer’s responsibility to be ready and
>   waiting to depart outside of the pickup location at the beginning of
>   the 15-minute window, and remain for the full designated 15-minute
>   pickup window.** Failure to do so may inhibit our ability to provide
>   service and may result in possible forfeiture of fare.

Their website also states that no refund is due if you are a "no show", which is a fairly standard condition of services like this :

> SuperShuttle will **not provide a refund** if the reservation is cancelled
>   or changed less than 2 hours prior to pick-up time, or **in the event of
>   reservation abandonment.**

However they also claim that they will attempt to contact you using the phone number you provided :

> Reservation abandonment occurs when the Operator cannot find the
>   customer at the designated pick-up location and cannot reach the
>   customer for further instruction using the “Day of Travel” contact
>   number provided within a short, reasonable time period, so as not to
>   jeopardize pick-up of other shared-ride passengers.

If you did provide a valid phone number, and if they did not attempt to contact you on this number, then you **might** have a valid claim for a refund based on that fact.

Comment: It comes down to whether 10 minutes is a short, reasonable time period. I think it is, and it is unreasonable to expect them to wait longer than that. They could have been there as early as 4:25, they waited until 4:35. It's unreasonable to expect them to inconvenience other customers more than that.

Comment: If I provided them with my number but they didn't give me a call, might I get the refund ?

Comment: I would certainly be pushing for a refund on the grounds that they didn't call.  But if they say no, then the simple fact is you were late, and I think it's time to put it down to a life lesson and move on...

Comment: I've been on the other side of the coin, sitting in an airport shuttle which waited unreasonably long at several stops, where it should have continued immediately due to the customer not being ready.  Fortunately it was a small airport so the late airport arrival was not a major problem, but in other circumstances it could have been worse than an inconvenience.

Comment: @gerrit And I've been on the flip side of that (specifically, with SuperShuttle.) I was ready by the time they told me I was supposed to be (the beginning of the 15 minute window)... and they showed up 30 minutes before that. Apparently their dispatch was really stretching the time windows they promised to customers in order to avoid dispatching a separate van.

Comment: I have missed a flight due to waiting for passengers to board, though it was an off-site parking lot shuttle, not a scheduled transfer shuttle like the OP. Still this is a reminder that sometimes there is a tradeoff between making things convenient for one customer, inconveniencing another one.